# Neighbors claim to see our cat, but we can't find it

Tags: cats, lost-pet

When I was going out of town I left my inside cat with my friends, but it ran away on the very first day (this happened about 4 weeks ago), so she never got to know my friends. When asking the neighbors if they ever saw the cat, four of them said: Yes, one of them very confidently. They also claimed that they saw her attempting to catch rabbits. It seems that the cat is somewhere around, but we have never seen her.

My number one goal is to verify that this is our cat. Some neighbors offered to take a picture of it when they see it, but they never done that.

My friends and I (sometimes just me, sometimes just them) have walked around in the neighborhood looking for it, and tried calling it by name but to no avail.

Are there any other options that can be tried?

Also, some general information like: an inside cat is unlikely to survive catching rabbits (or other wildlife) for 4 weeks, would be helpful. This is in Seattle area, and I do see plenty of rabbits that neighborhood.

Let me know if I am missing any useful information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always try to setup a live trap where your neighbors most frequently see her. This is going to sound ridiculous but KFC works really good for catching cats, my coworker had done this to catch her cat (caught her on the same day).
You can also leave food and water outside your place as well to entice her to come back.

Yes it is possible for indoor cats to try and catch wildlife (doesn't mean they will be successful).

Good luck catching your cat!

Comment: It worked; we got the cat!