# My kitten ran away, what are the chances of her coming home and/or surviving?

Tags: cats, behavior, safety, outdoor

We have a 3-4 month old stray kitten. She's fed, loved, played with and taken to the vet. Today, my door was cracked open for 5 seconds and she ran out into the the woods. My husband and I tried looking for her, it's been over 4 hours. What are her chances of coming home and or surviving?

**Update**: kitten has returned.

Comment: https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/14948/7526 may be helpful

Comment: Where do you live? What's the weather like? What predators do you have in the woods? How long have you owned her? Please urgently set out at least one trap for her - with food.

Comment: Thank you all. I live in Ga. The weather is very comfortable. She has not returned home. We searched and called her all day. Its very hurtful. She always tr to get out today wow. In my ❤ i feel shes OK because shes loveable. My mind I'm scared. We put signs up its 11 p.m. She was running so fast

Comment: Shes been with us 2 month's. She was happy played with her toys and enjoyed us. I left outside tonight. My husband turned on all the outside lights nothing yet. Please pray her name is Lola. Thank you everyone

Comment: Hello  everyone and thank you. I went outside about 5 minutes ago and looked in bushes calling Lola, she came out and ran to me. I picked her up she seems fine very hungry. I thank God and each one of you. This was a scary ordeal. I will pray this never happens to any of you. Thank you again &God bless each of you. Lola is SAFE 

Comment: So glad she’s home. 

Comment: @Allerleirauh hey sorry I didn't scroll down, I saw the first one and assumed it was the only one :D now there is one left that I didn't convert to comment, but it is because that is not for the question author.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely your cat is really close to where you live, but really scared. When you can't see it, it is very likely alive and well, but scared.

Take a look under dense bushes and in small spaces. You will find it, but it can take some time or even a day or two. You'll also want to take a look up in the trees, too; it might be hiding there.

You can also wait until it gets dark and use a flashlight to look for the reflections of your cat's eyes, as your cat might be too scared to come out to you.

Comment: the reason i say the cat is close by is i have allways taken my cats on walks in the forrest and when we met dogs my cats did hide and no matter  what i did they refused to come to me,so i completed my walk and returned to where my cats got lost later and they allways was there hiding close to where they got lost,(my point is cats dont run far in an unknown area normaly).